# Skype not showing people online on ubuntu?

Tags: skype

I installed skype using terminal, after i updated to 16.04, now only few people appear on-line on my contact list when compared to windows and also i tried sending message to one of my contact via Ubuntu it did not get sent when i checked it through windows

Answer (score 4):

Open a conversation window with anyone (doesn't matter, since you wont be messaging him). then type this:

```
/msnp24
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and restart Skype.

([Source](//www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/41idg2/really_weird_problem_with_skype_on_ubuntu/cz2xb2h))

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/41idg2/really_weird_problem_with_skype_on_ubuntu/:

Comment: omg that worked thanks now i am getting mirage of messages

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> this will open terminal.
Now issue the following commands

```
sudo apt-get purge skype*
sudo apt-get autoremove
rm -fr ~/.Skype
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Make sure that canonical partner repositories are enabled by going to settings --> Other software

Now go to terminal and issue the following command

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype
```

If you get any unmet dependency error then do

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install skype
```

Go to Ubuntu logo and type skype , click on the skype icon Skype application opens

Login, that's it.

If you face any issue with skype webcam you can refer to

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SkypeWebCams

Comment: I followed the instructions but i am facing the same problem, i don't see all my contacts online,  i can send and receive message from only few contact. For example i see a message that was sent to me in windows but not in Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you please check with your offline contacts whether both of you are using the same version of Skype? The Skype version obtained from official Ubuntu repository is mostly not the latest one. It is because a software version is thoroughly tested before being available via repository.

Comment: ok i will check that. is there a way to install the other version ? i remember i used wget to download the tar file last time

Comment: Surely there are other options. You can go to official skype website and download the *.deb installer package for ubuntu.  For installing you need to issue the following commands in terminal: sudo apt install gdebi, sudo gdebi abc.debi. That's it. (Replace 'abc' with actual package name. In this way you can get the latest version. However do remember that this is not the preferred way to get things done in Linux. Applications outside trusted repositories are not tested thoroughly for your Linux build and may bring instability. Also such applications may contain malware  that can infect your PC

Comment: yes i understand that i always use terminal to install application in linux but skype is really important to me and i want it to function well.

Comment: No the question is not about using terminal. For example you can use synaptic which has nice Graphical User Interface. It is about installing software from trusted repositories only. In case of skype, if you download the application from their website directly then it is the non tested version for your ubuntu buid and may or may not bring instability